# Как в PHP удалять cookie при закрытии сайта?

Tags: php, cookie

Как в PHP удалять cookie при закрытии сайта?

Comment: с помощью php - никак.

Comment: Именно при закрытии вкладки с сайтом. Время жизни 0 - т.е. до закрытия браузера, не подходит ? (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: @Mike, а оно точно работает? А то сколько писали в инетах, что куки не стираются при закрытии браузера ни в какую.

Comment: @Visman По стандартам должны, раньше все браузеры так делали. Сейчас действительно пишут, что часть браузеров этого не делают или делают не всегда. Но тут без костылей на JS тогда уже не обойтись ...

Comment: js удоляйте, или же время жизни куки к примеру минут 15 указывайте среднее значение нахождения пользователя на сайте